# Rails not passing id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

im new with rails. currently im facing problem with it. i have 3 model which is

```
order, task, and order task.
```

in the ordertask, i try to pass id from show.html to edit.html, but the rails only pass 
    http://localhost:3000/orders_tasks/%23%3COrderTask::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000009c9a078%3E/edit

instead of id number.

here is my show.html.erb

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>Task
        </td>
        <td>Status:
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <% @status.each do |i| %>
        <td><%= i.task_id %>
        </td>
        <td><%= i.status %>
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>



<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_orders_task_path(@status) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', orders_tasks_path %>
```

here is my ordertask controller

```html
class OrdersTasksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
    def index
        @orders = Order.all
       @status = OrderTask.includes(:task,:order).where(order_id: params[:id])
    end
    def edit
    end
    def show  
    end
    
    
    def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end 
    
    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_status
       @status = OrderTask.includes(:task,:order).where(order_id: params[:id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
        params.require(:order_task,:order).permit(:order_id,:status)
    end
    
end
```

and here is my edit.html

```html
<%= form_for(@status, html: {class: 'form form-horizontal'}).first.id do |f| %>
  <% if @status.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<table class="table table-hover">
  
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.label "List of task" %>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.label "Status" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= f.task_id %>
            
            
        </td>
        <td><div class="dropdown">
            <%= f.select(:status,['In progress', 'Completed'], {}, {class: "control"})%> </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td><%= f.submit %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<% end %>
```

my order model

```html
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :service
  
    
    
   has_many :order_task 
    has_many :tasks , through: :order_task
    

    validates :staff_id , presence: true
end
```

my task model

```html
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_task
    has_many :orders , through: :order_task
    attr_accessor :status, :task_type
    
    validates :task_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

and lastly my order task model

```html
class OrderTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = [:order_id]
    self.table_name = "Orders_tasks"
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :task
    

end
```

i hope you guys can help me out cause i have stuck with this problem for a week now. :D

Comment: I think your `@status` variable is an collection of objects but `show` and `edit` action requires single object. try to pass single object to these actions your problem will get resolved

Comment: You can do like this `edit_orders_task_path(@status.first)` OR `edit_orders_task_path(@status.last)` this will pass single object to *edit* action.

Comment: yes, thank you. :D. now im facing problem in displaying the join table in the _form.html. should i create another loop inside the form to display the task_id and its status?

Comment: on `edit` form do you want to edit single `order_task` or multiple `order_tasks` ?

Comment: as ordertask is a join table, i want to able to edit multiple status base on order_id. is it possible?? im kinda lost in the looping process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the edit links in the loop... since @status contains multiple ordertaks, and each ordertask should have his own edit page:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>Task
        </td>
        <td>Status:
        </td>
        <td>Action:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <% @status.each do |i| %>
        <td><%= i.task_id %>
        </td>
        <td><%= i.status %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_orders_task_path(i) %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Back', orders_tasks_path %>
```

**Edit**: But I do like to point out that most of the time you're not in need of Controllers for your join models. So I do not know why you think you need it, most of the logic can be build from either the OrdersController or the TasksController.

Comment: i see.. i thought each model have to have their own controller as the join table involve in many to many relationship. i will try this code. thx! :D

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't manipulate records from a many to many relationship directly, always use the related task or order to assign the relationships (checkboxes or multiple selects). If you have additional columns in the join table you should use nested forms (check out coccon gem in that case).

Comment: i almost forgot my main reason im doing this, i only want to update specific `status` of the `task` based on `order_id` and `task_id`. now im studying the cocoon gem and hope i can do it.